# Best Practices Way to Edit Magento Top-Links

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, theme, configuration, toplinks

Let's say we want to add a shopping cart icon right before the "My Cart" link on Magento's top links (see top links below).

[image]

What is the best way to do this?

1. Do something to toplinks.php?
2. Do something to links.phtml?
3. An xml file?
4. Any other options?

I understand that this can be done with CSS, but as my needs for customization grow, I want to know how this can be done without CSS so I am able to customize more difficult things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In any case do not edit the template file (`links.phtml`). This serves as a general template for all link lists. For example it is used for the links in the footer also.
With `toplinks.php` you can do whatever you want because is deprecated since CE v1.4.0.1.
I recommend using the xml files that add the links to the top container to achieve what you need.
The `addLink` method that is called when adding a new link supports some parameters that allow you to add classes and other attributes on `li` and `a` tags in the links and some text before the link and after the link.

```
public function addLink($label, $url='', $title='', $prepare=false, $urlParams=array(),
        $position=null, $liParams=null, $aParams=null, $beforeText='', $afterText='')
    { ... }
```

If you want to add an icon to my account menu you can set the `$beforeText` to `<span class="icon"></span>` and add some styles on the icon class.
For the cart and checkout links it's a little trickier because they are added via a block object not directly from the layout file.
If you need something different for the cart or checkout lins all you have to do is override the methods `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links::addCartLink()` or `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links::addCheckoutLink()`. These 2 call the same `addLink()` and you can pass different parameters to it.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for. I definitely have a lot of learning in front of me, but now I have an idea on where to start. I am going to try to add my icon (from bootstrap) with the following text $beforeText='<i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>' - Thank you!

Comment: Which XML file would I use for this?

Comment: I explained that for the cart and checkout links you cannot do this from the layout file. You need to override the method `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links::addCartLink()`

Comment: Ok. I am assuming to override the method I need to add a file to my custom theme files and call the method there, which will override its previous instance. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction, for example, which file would contain the Mage_Checkout_Block_Links method. Is it links.php?

Comment: If you go the XML route (which you definitely should) take note, that in order to use `<span class="icon"></span>` as the beforeText you have to enclose it like so `<![CDATA[<span class="icon"></span>]]>`. The XML parser picks up new lines too, so you have to put it right after the opening tag: `<beforeText><![CDATA[<span class="icon"></span>]]></beforeText>`

Answer (score 9):

In case you need to apply custom template only for Top Links, you can do it like this in your theme's local.xml:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">

        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/template/my_links.phtml</template>
        </action>

    </reference>
<default>
```

Then copy *page/template/links.phtml* and rename it to **page/template/my_links.phtml** and do whatever you need inside that new template file.

To add a custom link to Top Links via local.xml:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>My Link</label>
        <url>path/to/page</url>
        <title>My link tooltip</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>150</position>
        <liParams>id="my-custom-id"</liParams>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Also see this page: http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way

Comment: Using this method, would I be able to add html between each link?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Yes, in **links.phtml** there is a loop `<?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>`. You can add any HTML inside that loop.

Comment: But then it would be added to each link, yes? I am looking to add customized html between each link. Also, I believe the foreach loop gets used for the footer links as well as the header links so if I add html between links, they will be also applied to the footer links.

Comment: That's the trick: after you create *page/template/my_links.phtml* (which is a copy of original *links.phtml*) and after you add the code I posted to your *local.xml*, that template will be used **only** to render Top Links. Not footer links or any other links.

Comment: Oh, nice! +1 for that my friend! That will surely come in handy. For now I want to know how to add these different html for each link. I suppose I could do that with some variables and if statements in the php foreach loop, but I am trying to get this to work with extending an xml class. Do you know anything about config.xml and the app/code/local folder?

Comment: @Raphael It will be hard to do more using only XML, at least I don't know more. You can of course add custom links via XML, I added an example to my post.

Comment: Zitix, perhaps you can learn from this too if you need it. I successfully overrided the xml code to add html right before the My Cart link and only the My Cart link. Pretty cool stuff!

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/how-to-override-mage-checkout-block-links

Comment: I'm having tremendous difficulty with this.... :( I think to be honest there is something wrong with the config of my store. Tried the above suggestion, i.e. adding code to the local.xml file being created. But no changes at all happening for us. How would we begin to look into why this local.xml file is not working for us? I'm tried it in 3 folder locations. Our customer theme, the default theme and the base theme area too. No change after flushing cache etc... any ideas?

Comment: Do I have to name my file local.xml or is the name irrelevant? I named it recaptcha.xml and it does not work:::

Answer (score 0):

Please find this path to change top links :

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
```

and search for: Log In (In my case).

Now change title and label with your desired text.

Comment: You should not edit core files!

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit the following 2 files.

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/checkout.xml

app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/customer.xml
```

In these files, the links are added in `name="top.links"`. Just comment them out.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. While this answer works, the question was explicitly about *best practices* and editing core files is anything but best practice in Magento.