# How to Override Mage_Checkout_Block_Links

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, theme, overrides

What is the proper way to override a method, for example, the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links::addCartLink()` method.

My goal is to add some HTML before the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links::addCartLink()` method. However, I don't know where to begin or which file to copy and edit under my custom theme.

I am thinking about something like this:

```
public function addLink($beforeText='<i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a small tutorial on how to override a block a model or a helper: http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/
Keep this link save...you will need it in the future.
Now for your problem...following the tutorial in the link above
Create your own extension. Lets' call it 'Easylife_Checkout'. You will need to following files:
`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Checkout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Checkout>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Checkout>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Checkout/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Checkout>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Easylife_Checkout>
    </modules>
        <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <links>Easylife_Checkout_Block_Links</links>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
        </global>
</config>
```

and `app/code/local/Easylife/Checkout/Block/Links.php`

```
<?php
class Easylife_Checkout_Block_Links extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Links{
    public function addCartLink()
    {
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            $count = $this->getSummaryQty() ? $this->getSummaryQty()
                : $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
            if ($count == 1) {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s item)', $count);
            } elseif ($count > 0) {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s items)', $count);
            } else {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart');
            }

            $parentBlock->removeLinkByUrl($this->getUrl('checkout/cart'));
            $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"', '<i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>');//this will add the link. The last parameter is the 'before text'. You can add an other parameter after that that means $afterText
        }
        return $this;
    } 
}
```

Clear the cache and you should be done.

Comment: I appreciate this very, very much!

Comment: app/code/local/Easylife  ...  Are you sure that is the correct path?  App/code does not have a 'local' folder but there is app/locale/ ....    Should I create the local folder inside code?

Comment: yeah...the 'app/code/local' folder does not exist. Just create it.

Comment: I very carefully created these files exactly as posted and inserted them to the correct folders. I cleared the cache. I inspected the HTML with Chrome's Inspect Element tool, and I see no changes. I learned about how magento uses the local folder to override files located in the core folder. Is there a way to test to see if these files are being used?

Comment: So, I deleted the Links.php file found under app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Links.php and cleared the cache once again and found that the Add Cart and Checkout links disappeared. I am assuming something is wrong with the addLink() method since they do not get added back after being removed. Any ideas?

Comment: Or perhaps the error is in the Easylife_Checkout.xml or config.xml file because I deleted the Link.php file from the core and added the same file to my local folder and still the My Cart and Checkout links are gone.

Comment: So, making progress, the config file was missing the closing tags of the checkout and global tags. After that, however, the page doesn't load due to an error on line 2 of the Links.php file.

Comment: After replacing the new Links.php file with the original Links.php file in my local directory (to verify if the config.xml and Easylife_checkout.xml files were working), I get the following error: Fatal error: Class 'Easylife_Checkout_Block_Links' not found in /homepages/46/d271359246/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491

Comment: OK. I've reexamined the code I posted. I had 2 errors. I forgot the '/' in 2 closing tags in file config.xml. I've updated the response. I also tested the code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I got it working too now. One question, in the tutorial example you showed me, they used global > models  and you used global > blocks. Why the difference?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to override. In the tutorial a model was overwritten. You needed to override a block. In the same way you can override a helper.

Comment: Marius thanks very much for your help today!