# Add filter to getLoadedProductCollection()

Tags: product, attributes, collection, ce-1.9.0.0

In my magento store (ce-1.9.0) I have setup a custom product attribute:

```
custom_depth_check
```

And the attribute has the setting of

```
Used in Product Listing : Yes
Used for Sorting in Product Listing : Yes
```

I now need to filter any `getLoadedProductCollection()` with this attribute. The attribute will either be set at:

```
null
0
1
```

I need to filter all instances of `getLoadedProductCollection()` so that it will EXLCUDE any products with

```
custom_depth_check : 1
```

I have tried to clear and reload like so:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()
->clear()
->addAttributeToFilter('custom_depth_check', array('neq' => 1));
```

But that results in an empty collection. I also tried adding `->load()` at the end but again nothing comes up.

I have to stored this collection into an array for specific field such as name, price, description, images etc.

how can i achieve this.

Comment: The issue here is that it `getLoadedProductCollection`  probably returns a collection which has been `loaded`. All filters etc have already been applied and it is now immutable. Are you using `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List:getLoadedProductCollection` ?

Comment: Yep, I also tried making a local version of that List.php file and trying to add it in there but couldn't see how - on line #56 - `protected function _getProductCollection()`

Comment: Reckon I've got it. In your local version of `List.php` copy down the functionality from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection`

You'll want to add your new filter right below the `addAttributeToSelect` line. I think one of the `addMinimalPrice`, `addUrlRewrite` etc are loading the collection ahead of what you want.

Comment: To confirm - am I making a local copy of `Layer.php` and adding my filter in there? (line 120?) or copying that function and using it in my local copy of `List.php`?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/how-to-override-mage-checkout-block-links

Using the info in there you should be able to rewrite it the block to re-define only the method you want.

An alternative (and preferred solution) is to create a new block extending the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and make a layout xml update to tell the code to use your block.

Comment: Did this all work out for ya? I'll pop it as answer if so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List:getLoadedProductCollection` returns a loaded product collection. Meaning that it has already had all filters applied to it etc and has actually run the query.

To add new parameters to this query you need to rewrite/override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection` and pop your extra filters in right below the filters already present. Make sure it's above the `addMInimumPrice` etc as one of these is going to be the thing causing your collection to be loaded.

You can see the instruction here on how to rewrite this block ([How to Override Mage_Checkout_Block_Links](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/how-to-override-mage-checkout-block-links)).

An alternative (and my preferred solution) is to create a new block extending the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and make a layout xml update to tell the code to use your block.

Either way, that's all that needed. Glad to have helped.