# Edit drop down menu in RWD theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, link, drop-downs

I've looked into trying to edit some of the title links in the client account drop down menu?  I've looked in the links.phtml but the links themselves are being called elsewhere...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.Change My Account,Register, Login links via 
   **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml**

2. Change Cart& checkout links via 
   **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/checkout.xml**

3.Change wishlist links via **app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/wishlist.xml**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your theme's local.xml:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">

        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/template/my_links.phtml</template>
        </action>

    </reference>
<default>
```

Then copy *page/template/links.phtml* and rename it to **page/template/my_links.phtml** and do whatever you need inside that new template file.

To add a custom link to Top Links via local.xml:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>My Link</label>
        <url>path/to/page</url>
        <title>My link tooltip</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>150</position>
        <liParams>id="my-custom-id"</liParams>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Also see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/how-to-override-mage-checkout-block-links)