# Modify top links Magento 1.7

Tags: theme, blocks, login, wishlist

im just developing a new site, and havent used Magento for a while.

I have downloaded Magento 1.7.0.2 and have been playing around with CSS based on the blank theme, in my own theme folders.

Now is the time i would like to delete and modified some of the top links by the search box, and i have been into customer.xml and tried to modified the addlinks and even delete them entirely! but to no avail, nothing changed what-so-ever.

Am i missing something?

What is the correct way to modify the links at the top near the search bar?

Thanks

Comment: If you would like help troubleshooting something, then you need to tell us *exactly* what you tried, not tell us that what you did failed to result in anything. If nothing you tried did anything though, it begs the question: have you cleared and/or disabled Magento's caches?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it indirectly solved the problem! i stupidly forgot to flush the cache! But one more question, where can i find where the my cart and checkout links are? to also remove them from the top links? what file?

Comment: /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml:38

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practices Way to Edit Magento Top-Links](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/best-practices-way-to-edit-magento-top-links)

Answer (score 4):

To remove url from top links you can do this in local.xml of you theme using following code -

```
<default>
  <reference name="top.links"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
      <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl" />
    </action> 
  </reference>
</default>
```

You can add custom link by adding following code in local.xml file -

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
        <label>My Link</label>
        <url>path/to/page</url>
        <title>My link tooltip</title>
        <prepare>true</prepare>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>150</position>
        <liParams>id="my-custom-id"</liParams>
    </action>
</reference>
```

check out this for refernce: http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way

Comment: Which local.xml file is it we should be editing? The location of it isn't detailed in any of the links posted. Unless I'm being blind as a bat....?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, sorted my issues.

The first problem i forgot to empty my magento cache so the site wasn't updating correctly, to do this go to:

System-Cache Management - click flush magento cache

My second problem of where to find the checkout and my cart top links. In version 1.7.0.2 the links are in the checkout.xml

Thanks for all your help guys