# What is the best way to edit your Magento site's toplinks block in the top right hand corner, WITHOUT editing core files?

Tags: module, cms, frontend, overrides, core

This is the block which contains "My Account", "Log In/Log Out" etc by default.

I've seen a few suggestions on how to do this, but I haven't seen anything complete that doesn't involve editing core Magento files that will be overwritten in the next Magento update. Can a suggestion be mode on the best way to do this? I would imagine creating some files in the local folder pool to over ride the default file that would include a local.xml file? A full complete answer that details this step by step would be great, as this doesn't seem to exist. Almost looking for a "dummies guide" to be honest :)

Comment: Do you mean the topLinks block at top right in default theme or the category navigation?

Comment: @benmarks inquiring minds want to know...

Comment: @philwinkle Imma ask a question about cat nav just so you can copy your answer over. Hippy.

Comment: @benmarks If it turns out it's not catnav and it's literally toplinks .... I'll ask and answer my own question lol

Comment: @benmarks Sorry, I should have made that clearer. It's the topLinks block at the top right corner of each page. So "My Account", "Log In/Log Out" etc. Not the category navigation.

Comment: Sorry @philwhinkle I read through your whole answer before realising you were talking about category navigation. Good answer all the same though! ;)

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking there aren't already tons of resources that detail how to edit toplinks using local or layout xml? Such as: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/best-practices-way-to-edit-magento-top-links --- Or is this a case of wanting to replace that block entirely? Why not just remove it with local/layout xml and use your own block class?

Comment: Yeah, I've read through articles like that. And I suppose that will work. If I don't have a local or layout.xml file in my layout folder within my theme should I be worried...? Neither of these files are in the default theme layout folder either, nor the base/layout folder.... the only local.xml file I can locate is the 1 located in app/etc which I imagine is not to be touched...? Contains DB and admin details etc.

Comment: I guess I should just create the local.xml file in the location needed if it is not there?

Comment: Layout XML files are included with modules and are in the `design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/layout/`, such as `catalog.xml`. Top Links can be set in any of those layout files, though for tidyness you'll want to keep it somewhere practical. Alternatively, you can create a file in that layout folder called `local.xml` and this file will be parsed after all the other layout files. This makes it handy to store all your own customizations that are part of your theme but that aren't part of a specific module.

Comment: Cheers. I'll create a local.xml file in my layout folder. Feels like there should be 1 there. Can probably use it for other things too. Thanks for your help. Should manage to work it all out from here.

Comment: I'm having tremendous difficulty with this.... :( I think to be honest there is something wrong with the config of my store. Tried the above suggestion, i.e. adding code to the local.xml file being created. But no changes at all happening for us. How would we begin to look into why this local.xml file is not working for us? I'm tried it in 3 folder locations. Our customer theme, the default theme and the base theme area too. No change after flushing cache etc... any ideas?