# How to Edit/Change name of wishlist etc

Tags: theme, magento-1, localisation, helper

How to change/edit names in the top menu "Wishlist, My Cart and Checkout"?

Comment: are you taking about the top links

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/best-practices-way-to-edit-magento-top-links

Comment: Theme translations: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6722/how-to-implement-translations-in-design-template-package-csvs-how-does-echo-t/78483#78483

Answer (score 0):

For "My Cart" and "Checkout" links, you should override the related methods from ***`Mage_Checkout_Block_Links`*** (`addCartLink()` and `addCheckoutLink()`).

As for the wishlist, the block is ***`Mage_Wishlist_Block_Links`*** and the method is `_createLabel()`