# How to show currency flag and code on top header in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, header, multicurrency

My code is

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>  
<div class="header_currency">
    <div class="currency_box">
      <div class="currency_pan"> <i class="hideIcon fa fa-money"></i><span><?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?> - <?php echo $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()?>      

       </span><i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></div>
      <div class="currency_detail">
        <div class="currency-inner">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <a title="<?php echo $_name ?>" class="currency_icon  <?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected<?php endif; ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?> " onclick="setLocation(this.value);"> <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'flag/'.$_code.'.jpg'; ?>" title="<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>" alt="<?php echo $_name ?> - <?php echo $_code ?>" width="20" height="17" /> <?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol()?> <span>- <?php echo $_name ?></span></a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to change flag in header too.

[image]

some thing like :

[image]

Comment: its not clear what you want ?

Comment: have a look to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/best-practices-way-to-edit-magento-top-links?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: i want to show country flag on top of drop down like if i am selecting EURO from drop down list then flag will show in header also (before currency code)

Comment: you want to show the falg of selected country , like when you select `EURO` than after selection flag must be shown beside the currency code ?

Comment: yes but in header, in drop down its already showing . u can see in screenshot.

Comment: i addedd an image , is that you want ?

Comment: yes, exactly .. i want the same

Comment: i posted a solution may be it help you a bit

Answer (score 0):

May be its not the perfect solution but

whenever we change the currency a cookie is created VIZ `currency`.

You can change the flag image based on cookies in header part beside the dropdown.

Put all flag images under a folder like below and based on current cookie value change the flag image name.

`http://yourwebsite.in/skin/frontend/rwd/yourtheme/flags/USD.jpg`

To get Media URL [Media URL](https://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/magento-get-directory-paths-get-base-urls-get-urls-in-static-block-get-secure-url/)

Like : Mage::getBaseUrl('skin')

Comment: any Code for image fetch ?????

Comment: i updated my suggestion with the link from where you can learn about magento urls

Comment: If this helped you can mark it as accepted or I will try to update of code.